# Select array section using INDEX

Tags: arrays, vba, split

I have a 200x4 array, I need a subset from row 5 to 50, how can I do this **without loops**?

This is kind of what I had in mind, any suggestions?

**MyArray[5:50,]**

This is just in VBA, no information is used from the excel spreadsheet

Comment: just to make sure, is you array values read from a worksheet cells ? let's say from row 1 to 200, and you want to only read the values from row 5 to 50 ?

Comment: The values are the result another calculation in VBA, nothing linked to the excel sheet

Comment: [This link](https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/vba-trick-of-the-week-slicing-an-array-without-loop-application-index/) should provide a trick to do that, but I couldn't make it work

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible in pure VBA (although you can get some of what you want with the [Index function](https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/vba-trick-of-the-week-slicing-an-array-without-loop-application-index/).

What you could do is write a slicing function that abstracts the needed loops, so that the code which does the slicing is cleaner. Something like:

```
'Assumes 1-based arrays

Function Slice(A As Variant, Optional RowRange As String = "", Optional ColRange As String = ""):
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, rmin As Long, rmax As Long, cmin As Long, cmax As Long
    Dim m As Long, n As Long
    Dim S As Variant, Dims As Variant

    If Len(RowRange) > 0 Then
        Dims = Split(RowRange, ":")
        rmin = Dims(0)
        rmax = Dims(1)
    Else
        rmin = 1
        rmax = UBound(A, 1)
    End If

    If Len(ColRange) > 0 Then
        Dims = Split(ColRange, ":")
        cmin = Dims(0)
        cmax = Dims(1)
    Else
        cmin = 1
        cmax = UBound(A, 2)
    End If

    m = rmax - rmin + 1
    n = cmax - cmin + 1

    ReDim S(1 To m, 1 To n)
    For i = 1 To m
        For j = 1 To n
            S(i, j) = A(rmin + i - 1, cmin + j - 1)
        Next j
    Next i

    Slice = S
End Function
```

A partial test:

```
Sub test()
    Dim A As Variant
    A = Range("A1:C6").Value 'a 4x6 array

    Range("E1:G3").Value = Slice(A, "2:4")
    Range("E5:F10").Value = Slice(A, , "1:2")
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Unfortunately, `Slice(A, "2:4",)` is a syntax error -- in VBA function calls you can't terminate the argument list with a comma, even if the remaining parameters are optional, hence the asymmetry of `Slice(A, "2:4")` vs. `Slice(A, , "1:2")`.